# I want to use for loop in jinja2 template with specific conditions

Tags: python, for-loop, flask, jinja2

I just starting learned python. I want to add for loop in Jinja2 template, there is a condition I have 2 sections and their positions are left and right with different div (div for left section and div for right section ) as you can see in the image and code. So how to add for loop in this scenario so that sections are aligned automatically left and right.

```html
<div class="timelines-container mbr-pt-4 mbr-white">

<!--1 Left-->
<div class="timeline-element separline mbr-pb-4">
<div class="timeline-wrap mbr-flex">
<div class="timeline-img-wrap mbr-col-sm-12 mbr-col-md-6 mbr-flex">
<div class="timeline-img-panel">
<amp-img alt="" class="Intellemo-loader" height="170" layout="responsive" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/07/17/22/43/student-849825__340.jpg" width="250">
<div class="placeholder" placeholder="">
<div class="mobirise-spinner">
<em></em>
<em></em>
<em></em>
</div></div>
<a href="top-5-marketing-reporting-tools.html"></a>
<amp-img alt="Marketing-Reporting-Tools" class="Intellemo-loader" fallback height="170" layout="responsive" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/07/17/22/43/student-849825__340.jpg" width="250">
<div class="placeholder" placeholder="">
<div class="mobirise-spinner">
<em></em>
<em></em>
<em></em>
</div></div>
<a href="top-5-marketing-reporting-tools.html"></a>
</amp-img></amp-img>
<div class="timeline-text-content">
<a href="top-5-marketing-reporting-tools.html">
<h4 class="mbr-timeline-title mbr-black mbr-fonts-style display-2 mbr-pb-2" style="padding-bottom: 0px;">Top 5 Marketing Reporting Tools</h4></a>
<p class="mbr-timeline-text mbr-fonts-style display-12 mbr-timeline-text mbr-black">Are you one amongst those digital marketers who feel creating reports is one of the most boring and tedious tasks or somebody...</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="timeline-item-wrap mbr-col-sm-12 mbr-col-md-6 mbr-flex mbr-column align-left">
</div>
<span class="iconBackground"></span>
</div>
</div>


<!--2 Right-->
<div class="timeline-element separline mbr-pb-4">
<div class="timeline-wrap mbr-flex mbr-row-reverse">
<div class="timeline-img-wrap mbr-col-sm-12 mbr-col-md-6 mbr-flex">
<div class="timeline-img-panel">
<amp-img alt="CRM-Benefits" class="Intellemo-loader" height="170" layout="responsive" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/07/17/22/43/student-849825__340.jpg" width="250">
<div class="placeholder" placeholder="">
<div class="mobirise-spinner">
<em></em>
<em></em>
<em></em>
</div></div>
<a href="crm-software-benefits.html"></a>
<amp-img alt="CRM-Benefits" class="Intellemo-loader" fallback height="170" layout="responsive" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/07/17/22/43/student-849825__340.jpg" width="250">
<div class="placeholder" placeholder="">
<div class="mobirise-spinner">
<em></em>
<em></em>
<em></em>
</div></div>
<a href="crm-software-benefits.html"></a>
</amp-img></amp-img>
<div class="timeline-text-content">
<a href="crm-software-benefits.html">
<h4 class="mbr-timeline-title mbr-black mbr-fonts-style display-2 mbr-pb-2" style="padding-bottom: 0px;">CRM Benefits Explained</h4></a>
<p class="mbr-timeline-text mbr-fonts-style display-12 mbr-timeline-text mbr-black">Explained Better Sales Prospects Follow the quality leads by converting opportunity and reducing the sales cycle...</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="timeline-item-wrap mbr-col-sm-12 mbr-col-md-6 mbr-flex mbr-column">
</div>
<span class="iconBackground"></span>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

[Screenshot of left and right sections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TV1a.png)

Comment: Am I right that you have a list of content items that you want to render partially on the left side and partially on the right?

Comment: Yes,  Sergey Shubin.

Answer (score 0):

```
#To add for loop in jinja2 syntax as follows:-
{% for post in posts%}
#content
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: Thank you, Mayur. But this is only helpful when there is only one section, here I have two different sections and I want to cover both sections in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

It looks you have a list of items and you want to render the items with even indexes (0, 2, 4,..) on the left and the ones with odd indexes (1, 3, 5,..) on the right. You can make 2 loops and use [jinja even test](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#even) to filter items for each of the loops:

```html
<div class="left-column">
<!-- For items with 0, 2, 4,.. indexes -->
{% for item in item_list %}
  {% if loop.index0 is even %}
    {{ item }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>

<div class="right-column">
<!-- For items with 1, 3, 5,.. indexes -->
{% for item in item_list %}
  {% if loop.index0 is not even %}
    {{ item }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

`loop` is a special jinja variable available in loops. It can be used for [various useful operations](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#for) like getting current loop index, checking if it is the first or the last loop etc.